eslint rule forbidding to check numbers as is
Is there an eslint rule which yields an error for the following code:
function parseNumber(numberToCheck: number | undefined) {
  // I want an error here: !0 is true, so we will get "no number" here
  if (!numberToCheck) {
    return "no number";
  } else {
    return "number";
  }
}

The if (!number) {...} check is so annoying and has caused so many errors, I'd really like to forbid this kind of checking.

Your looking for the @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions rule.
It is configurable to suit your needs:
const options: Options = [
  {
    allowNumber: false,
    allowNullableNumber: false,
  },
];

